# No wired and wireless connection found after upgrading 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

After upgrading 12.04 LTS, my wired connection works but *no wireless connection found*. I tried many suggestion for wireless connection on Ubuntu forum but nothing works for me.

Now, maybe by mistake, I am also *unable* to connect Internet through *wired connection*.

Now,
(1) its says "No network devices available" and
(2) in System Settings → Hardware → no additional driver icon is showing

Please help. I don't know much about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I know one method that needs the following equipment:

1.Mobile with GPRS connection or (LAN WIRED CONNECTION if available)

2.USB DATA CABLE for your mobile used to connect with your computer.

You need to connect the usb cable to your computer and then you can see mobile modem network signal in your Ubuntu network manager; now connect and configure the network (aircel, airtel or vodafone or others)

Disable proxy settings (if you have any), make sure you are connected to a mobile modem
and then open your Ubuntu software Center:

Install  *ADDITIONAL DRIVERS*

open *ADDITIONAL DRIVERS,*

then activate your wifi driver.